# Python Dataframe plot using Plotly client

Tags: python, plot, dataframe, plotly

I have following Python **data frame** and want to plot using **plotly** client. How can i plot as a line chart.

```
Date          A       B       C      D       E       F       G   
2008-03-18  24.68   164.93  114.73  26.27   19.21   28.87   63.44
2008-03-19  24.18   164.89  114.75  26.22   19.07   27.76   59.98
2008-03-20  23.99   164.63  115.04  25.78   19.01   27.04   59.61
2008-03-25  24.14   163.92  114.85  27.41   19.61   27.84   59.41
2008-03-26  24.44   163.45  114.84  26.86   19.53   28.02   60.09
2008-03-27  24.38   163.46  115.4   27.09   19.72   28.25   59.62
2008-03-28  24.32   163.22  115.56  27.13   19.63   28.24   58.65
2008-03-31  24.19   164.02  115.54  26.74   19.55   28.43   59.2
2008-04-01  23.81   163.59  115.72  27.82   20.21   29.17   56.18
2008-04-02  24.03   163.32  115.11  28.22   20.42   29.38   56.64
2008-04-03  24.34   163.34  115.17  28.14   20.36   29.51   57.49
```

Date as X-axis and A B C D E F G  as Y-axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try using cufflinks with Plotly. Cufflinks binds plotly directly to pandas dataframes.

```
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly.plotly as py
df.iplot(kind='scatter')
```

From here: https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/

This assumes the Date column is the dataframe index.

If the 'Date' column is not the dataframe index, specify it as the x-axis with x:

```
df.iplot(x='Date',kind='scatter')
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Pandas, Cufflinks and Plotly

---

Here is some piece of code to solve this problem.
Tried with Jupyter Notebook

---

```
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

df = pd.read_csv('/home/user/data_directory/data.csv')

iplot({
     'data':
         [{'x': df['Date'],
           'y': df[col],
           'name': col
          } for col in df.columns[1:-1]],

     'layout':
         {'title':'A, B, C, D, E, F, G Time Series'}
}, show_link=False)
```

---

- We are using `plotly.offline` instead of `plotly.plotly` to avoid the necessity of having a plotly account;
- We are setting `show_link=False` to hide the link text: **Export to plotly >>** which usually appear at the bottom right of the Figure.

  ---